# Python Multi-Processing Question?

Tags: python, zeromq

I have a folder with 500 input files (total size of all files is ~ 500[MB]).

I'd like to write a `python` script that does the following:

**(1)** load all of the input files to memory

**(2)** initializes an empty `python` list that will later be used ... see bullet **(4)**

**(3)** start 15 different (independent) processes: each of these uses the same input data [from `(1)`] -- yet uses a different algorithms to processes it, thus generating different results

**(4)** I'd like all the independent processes [from step `(3)`] to store their output in the same `python` list [same list that was initialized in step `(2)`]

Once all 15 processes have completed their run, I will have `one python list` that includes the results of all the 15 independent processes.

My question is, is it possible to do the above efficiently in `python`? if so, can you provide a scheme / sample code that illustrates how to do so?

**Note #1:** I will be running this on a strong, multi-core server; so the goal here is to use all the processing power while sharing some memory {`input data`, `output list`} among all the independent processes.

**Note #2:** I am working in a `Linux` environment

Comment: This is not going to work nicely at all. With all of the contention over the one list, you're probably not going to see much of a gain from concurrency.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: What would you suggest? my goal here is to be able to 'aggregate' the results at the end of the processing; what are the alternatives? (just to make things clear, the `output list` will be of size ~ 100[MB]).

Comment: i can kind of see it working with zeromq. multiple publishers, one subscriber. and the subscriber manages the list.

so the questions I have is #1: are 3rd part libraries on the table? and #2: how does the output get represented?

Comment: I'd work on independent lists and then aggregate them at once. Obviously, that approach will use more memory, so you may have to go to disk some.

Comment: @Tom Willis: thank you; Answers to your questions: `#1` --> no, no 3rd part libraries; I am basically using only standard `python` libraries; `#2` --> the output list will probably be a multi-dimensional array, ideally using `numpy`; either way, it will only contain numbers (or arrays with numbers given the multi-dimensionality). Can you elaborate how `zeromq` should be used here? will this solution utilize all the computing power of the server?

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: I don't want to go to disk; it will slow me down; setting this aside, how do I use all the computing power of the server and have 15 processes that all share the same input data?

Comment: @user that is a classic problem of concurrency, and not an easy one to solve.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: Is it possible to solve this in `python`? If so, can you suggest what libraries to use / how to approach this?

Comment: @user3262424 as you can see I put a demo app together demonstrating how to do something similar with 0mq. I think the crux of the issue is the communication between processes. zeromq makes this a lot easier than the mechanisms provided by multiprocessing IMO. the value it adds for your specific problem is one subscriber communicating with multiple publishers. anyway hope that helps

Comment: To use all the processing of the server with Python, you must have multiple processes, at least one per core. Also, you need them to be loosely coupled, i.e. use non-blocking communications such as ZeroMQ. People often try to use pipes but then block their worker processes. Easier to use ZeroMQ

Comment: @Michael Dillon: thanks. So `zeroMQ` if one wants to run one `master` process and many (say, `N`) child processes that are related to it? (say, share the same memory? same output?)

Comment: ZeroMQ lets you run as many loosely coupled independent processes as you want, either on the same server or on hundreds of servers. ZeroMQ is an extension of the point-to-point socket that only has two ends. A ZeroMQ socket can have one SUB end at the master process, and many PUB ends at several independent worker processes.

Comment: @Michael Dillon: I did not understand anything about `SUB` and `PUB` -- can you explain further? Also, what happens to all processes if the master node fails?

Comment: Read the ZeroMQ guide to understand what PUB and SUB mean. http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all  As for your child processes, that is a separate question and it depends on how they are started and whether or not they daemonize themselves. On UNIX, when a process group leader dies, all of its children die too.

Comment: @Michael Dillon: thank you, I will read the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok I just whipped this up using [zeromq](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall) to demonstrate a single subscriber to multiple publishers. You could probably do the same with queues but you would need to manage them a bit more. zeromq sockets just work which makes it nice for things like this IMO.

```
"""
demo of multiple processes doing processing and publishing the results
to a common subscriber
"""
from multiprocessing import Process


class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, filename, bind):
        self._filename = filename
        self._bind = bind
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        import zmq
        import time
        ctx = zmq.Context()
        result_publisher = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
        result_publisher.bind(self._bind)
        time.sleep(1)
        with open(self._filename) as my_input:
            for l in my_input.readlines():
                result_publisher.send(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import os
    import zmq

    #assume every argument but the first is a file to be processed
    files = sys.argv[1:]

    # create a worker for each file to be processed if it exists pass
    # in a bind argument instructing the socket to communicate via ipc
    workers = [Worker(f, "ipc://%s_%s" % (f, i)) for i, f \
               in enumerate((x for x in files if os.path.exists(x)))]

    # create subscriber socket
    ctx = zmq.Context()

    result_subscriber = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
    result_subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")

    # wire up subscriber to whatever the worker is bound to 
    for w in workers:
        print w._bind
        result_subscriber.connect(w._bind)

    # start workers
    for w in workers:
        print "starting workers..."
        w.start()

    result = []

    # read from the subscriber and add it to the result list as long
    # as at least one worker is alive
    while [w for w in workers if w.is_alive()]:
        result.append(result_subscriber.recv())
    else:
        # output the result
        print result
```

oh and to get zmq just

```
$ pip install pyzmq-static
```

Comment: @Tom Willis: thank you! Will the above code use all the processing power of the server? also, can you confirm that the `list` that stores that output will be manipulated in-memory, without needing to access the disk? also, when I run the linux command `top` -- will I see 1 `python` process or 15 different processes?

Comment: you will see a process in top for each worker you run + the main process, in the code above that list is in memory, whether that's good or bad depends on your purposes. The only time the script above accesses the disk is to read the files that are passed in as arguments.  I merely wanted to demonstrate how the interprocess communication can be done and how easy it is with 0mq.

Comment: one final thing that might not be obvious. the messages between processes have to be strings. if you need more structure to your data, use something like json

Comment: +1 The original request is not really possible as written, but the right way to do this is to use multiple independent Python processes and zmq is a great way to tie them together. And if your multicore machine is not enough, then just change the socket to use tcp://my_ip_address:10001 and you can have them running on multiple machines with no problems. The mistake in the question was to load all the data into memory first, then start the processes. Leave it in the files, and send the answers to the master process over a PUB-SUB queue.

Comment: @Tom Willis: thank you. So, if I understand you right, the `child` processes will send `strings` to the master process? and these `strings` will have to be parsed and then stored in the output list? did I get it right? if so, is there a limit to the string size?

Comment: @Michael Dillon: If I don't load all the data into memory at first, each process will have to load them into memory -- thus wasting 15x as much memory (because the data is the same). does it make sense?  Also, can you elaborate on your alternative solution (and perhaps, provide a sample)? thank you

Comment: @user yep, an json makes a great transport format for that. as far as limits go on the message, I would have to consult the zeromq docs for that. I was only able to answer this because I had to figure out something very similar last night while hacking. :)

Comment: Regarding memory consumption, why not do a trial using mmap and then another run where you load all the files before forking. I think that there will be little difference assuming that you are on Linux. For that matter, why not ask another question specifically about these two alternatives?

Comment: @Michael Dillon: I guess both approaches can work. Need to see which one fits better. Just for me to get a sense, is `zmq` THE SOLUTION for any scalability issues? meaning, assuming you want a program to run on say 1000 processes (across `N` computers) -- `zmq` can be the *bridge* that connects them all to one master node?

Comment: @user you are very welcome. zeromq is really freaking cool. it makes interprocess communication very easy if your problem can be expressed as a mix of the network topology's it supports. spend a weekend playing around with it, follow along with the docs and you may find as I have that it opens up a whole world of possibilities for solving problems involving multiple processes.