# Multi-Core Python: multiprocessing Vs. zeroMQ?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zeromq

I'd like to write `python` code that loads a data set as input and analyzes it.

There will be 5 parallel processes that will analyze the data -- each process will be processing the data differently -- in a unique way.

Before any processing will begin, the `master` script (the one that will 'start' all the different sub-processes) will define an empty list.

I'd like all the different processes to write their output to the same list mentioned above (meaning, each one of the processes will be able to directly manipulate the list that was defined in the `master` script).

Meaning, if `process1` changed the first value of that list, all the other processes (while running) will see that the first value of that list has changed.

---

I get a sense that 2 different `python` modules can be used to solve this problem: `multiprocessing` and `zeroMQ`.

Are there any reasons to prefer one vs. the other in this case? does your answer change if -- instead of running the `master` script on the same server -- I will be splitting the processes between different (multiple) servers?

(if it at all matters, I am using a `Linux`)

Comment: I don't know what multiprocessing and zeromq should have in common and how they should be related here. It's more about how to do parallel processing (threads vs. processes) and how to implement communication between workers.

Comment: Sentinel: correct; yet, both `multiprocessing` and `zeroMQ` are modules through which one can do *parallel processing*. The question is, which one is more flexible / more suitable in this case? also, which one is more suitable when it is desired to 'cross the border' of one machine, and use multiple machines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Multi-Processing Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542192/python-multi-processing-question)

Comment: @Michael Dillon: it not a duplicate; rather, it is meant to provide some clues which approach is most suitable: using `multiprocessing` or `zeroMQ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>**If** these are your only two choices and you know for sure that you're going to be distributing your load across multiple machines, ZeroMQ is the only one of the two choices that fits the bill.</strike>

The Python multiprocessing module is for distributing load across processes/cores on a single machine.  As far as I know, there is no networked protocol underlying the multiprocessing module and this is indicated by the first paragraph in the [accompanying documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

ZeroMQ can be used for similar inter-process messaging on a single machine with its IPC protocol, but it also has network-based protocols that allows you to send messages between processes running on different machines as well.

That said, this question has the slight tinge of a an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) since you seem to have arbitrarily narrowed your choices to only two of the many, many possibilities for implementing a distributed program using Python.

**Edit** My answer here was incorrect and I can't delete an accepted answer, so converting it to a wiki in case anyone wants to correct it.  Short story is I misread the documentation in haste.  Python multiprocessing does support inter-process communication over a network boundary.  One major difference with ZeroMQ is that ZeroMQ is designed to be platform agnostic so you could mix client/server agents on different platforms whereas Python multiprocessing is a batteries included option if client/server processes are coupled to Python.

Comment: thank you. Can you provide some more information on the `many possibilities for implementing a distributed program using python`?

Comment: AMQP, Twisted, HTTP, Stomp, raw sockets, RDBMS - a lot of it depends on the nature of the application. For example, are you hoping to just pass pickled Python objects as your messages or are you going to marshal/unmarshal them into a more platform neutral representation?

Comment: Thank you. my messages will mostly pass data -- say, a `python` string, from a `master` node to many `child` nodes. Do you think that any of the above is more suitable to this than `zeroMQ`?

Comment: I'm a fan of ZeroMQ, so my intent wasn't to steer you away from that.  I just wanted to be clear (for future travelers) that there are more than two ways to do inter-process/distributed messaging in Python.

Comment: In fact, multiprocessing module can be used to create inter-process communication on networked systems. This can be accomplished with [Managers](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.managers).

Comment: From the docs, *The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency*...

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what I was smoking when I wrote this answer or what I read in the documentation to make me think it didn't have a remote API. Weird.

Answer (score 5):

You can't compare apples and oranges.

multiprocessing is a library to fork many processes.

zmq is a library that allows processes to use messages to communicate.

They do different jobs.

Comment: I guess the OP is asking about between multiprocessings queues and the zeromq way of doing things.

Comment: For me i write ZeroRPC , with Multiprocessing calls,distributed across servers and thats is fun!